# android studio отключить автосохранение

Tags: android-studio

как его отключить? когда слушаю музыку с плеера или ВК то после каждого написанного слова идет сохранение и комп на долю секунды тормозит и музыка тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Все галки здесь: File->Settings->Appearance and Behavior->System Settings->Synchronization

Comment: снял все галки, ничего не изменилось

Comment: А студию перезапускали после того, как галки поснимали?

Comment: перезапускал, 0 эффекта

Comment: значит дело не в сохранении. Торможение может быть связано с анализом кода студией. Импорт, автодополнение и т.д.